# Predicting next destination (for a car)

Tags: probability, predictive-models, modeling, conditional-probability, multinomial-distribution

I am trying to figure out how to predict the next destination of a an object (e.g. car) given its present location (and potentially last location), the type of object and potentially other factors as well.

I have a large amount of historical data on travel behavior to learn from and the data as a structure like:

| objectID | Type | DateTime | Departure_Location | Arrival_Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 736916 | local | 2020-10-11 15:20:00 | 742 | 26034 |
| 736916 | local | 2020-10-11 16:10:00 | 26034 | 16245 |
| 736916 | local | 2020-10-11 15:20:00 | 16245 | 635 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 937651 | regional | 2020-11-19 08:10:00 | 153 | 18264 |
| 937651 | regional | 2020-11-20 09:20:00 | 18264 | 153 |
| 937651 | regional | 2020-11-21 08:10:00 | 153 | 18264 |

There is a large finite set of possible locations (approx. 28.000 possible locations), but for a given object the actual set (historically) is quite small, i.e. the target follows a multinominal distribution.

How can I predict the most likely destination location?

I have thought about "just" brute force calculating probabilities based on the historical data (here using python)

```
originDestinationDF = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['ObjectID','Departure_Location', 'Arrival_Location', 'n', 'p(Arrival_Location|Departure_Location)']) #Dataframe for storing probabilities

for id in df['ObjectID'].unique():

    dfTempID = df[df['ObjectID'] == id]

    for location in dfTempID['Departure_Location'].unique():

        dfTempLoc = dfTempID[dfTempID['Departure_Location'] == location]

        N = dfTempLoc.shape[0]

        dftemp = pd.DataFrame(dfTempLoc.groupby('Arrival_Location')['Departure_Location'].count())

        dftemp = dftemp.rename(columns= {'Departure_Location': 'n'}, inplace = False)

        dftemp = dftemp.reset_index()

        dftemp['ObjectID'] = [id]*dftemp.shape[0]

        dftemp['Departure_Location'] = [location]*dftemp.shape[0]

        dftemp['p(Arrival_Location|Departure_Location)'] = dftemp.n/N

        originDestinationDF = originDestinationDF.append(dftemp, ignore_index = True)
```

This code would yield a dataframe similar to the following:

| ObjectID | Departure_Location | Arrival_Location | n | p(Arrival_Location|Departure_Location) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9208186 | 13415 | 12549 | 4 | 0.5 |
| 9208186 | 13415 | 1637 | 2 | 0.25 |
| 9208186 | 13415 | 26788 | 1 | 0.125 |
| 9208186 | 13415 | 153 | 1 | 0.125 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

It will be a fairly large portions of calculations with approx. 260.000 unique object, approx. 28.000 unique destinations and a large number of Departure-Arrival pairs for each Object.

Is there a smarter way of doing this?

I would also like to be able to make informed predictions in situations where $n$ Objects departs from a location it had not been located at before.

Comment: A shot in the dark: Maybe experiment with reformulating *prediction* as *recommendation*, so you could make a recommendation system recommending where the car should go, based on the historical data? Search this site ...